# Can I make parental searches on Bing / Google?

Tags: google-search, search, bing, access-control

Is it possible to make searches on Bing, Google or another search machine, that will only show results that is, for example, [PG-rated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system#From_M_to_PG)?

For example, if I wanted to send a school student to search on the [Bikini islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bikini_Atoll), a place where there has been done A-bomb tests, I'm sure it would be easy to get a lot of unwanted material in the form of swim suit pictures, magazines, etc. Would it be possible to get the search engine remove those results instead of using parental desktop tools, to block those sites?

Answer (score 3):

In Google, "Search settings", "SafeSearch Filtering", setting your search filter to ['strict'](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=510) will return you pretty good safe results.

In Bing, under "Preferences", use the "disable filtering" dialog. It allows to display parental hits. See [bing.com/settings.aspx](http://bing.com/settings.aspx).

Comment: you did that once or twice, hu? :)

add "and the same in the preferences of bing" and you have a complete answer.

Comment: LOL, I don't know *what* you're talking about.

Comment: bing.com has under "prefences" the same "disable filtering" dialog as google. same effect, it allows them to display parental hits. see http://www.bing.com/settings.aspx ... just add this to your answer and it is complete.

Comment: nice additional info.

Comment: Since I haven't noticed that google has been removing all adult pictures, I think the effect is quite limited.

Comment: All automated filtering is subject to error - it's not an exact science. You should never rely on getting 100% safe results from even a strict search. However, I'd wager that most school students have seen more than bikini pictures on the web :)